# How does multiple assignment in Fibonacci code used in Python website work?

Tags: python, sequence, fibonacci

I'm a newbie to Python and just can't understand this:
Code#1:

```
a, b = 0, 1
while a < 10:
    print(a)
    a, b = b, a+b
```

Code#2

```
a, b = 0, 1
while a < 10:
    print(a)
    a = b
    b = a+b
```

Why Code#1 produce Fibonacci sequence while Code#2 doesn't?

Comment: You've set `a = b` you've lost the value of `a` when you do `b = a+b` which really is `b = b + b`. You'd normally have to use a third, intermediate variable in other languages, but python has multiple assignment/iterable unpacking syntax to do it without an extra variable.

Comment: Yeah. I've added `c = a + b`  and `b = c` and It worked! Tnx;